# Multiple MS Access Front end Connections to a Single remote SQL Server Back end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2014, tcp, ms-access-2016

Situation:

I have successfully split an MS Access Database into a Front end (MS Access) and a linked named SQL Server Back end on the same machine. Things work exceptionally well. This was done using the linked Table Manager create new data source, driver SQL Server. Server `COMPUTERNAME\NAMEDSQLINSTANCE`, Windows NT authorization, Default Database as Back end database name, Test Connection succeeded. Changes in on Front-end reflected in the Backend and changes in Back End reflected in the front end. Life is good.

However,

I need to have 5 other machines (not in the same domain, Not on a network, not on the same service provider, just stand-alone machines with internet access) to link to this named SQL Server Back which is on yet another stand-alone machine with only internet access.

I have configured the SQL Database to accept remote connections. I have configured the Windows Firewall on the SQL machine to use port **1433** for the SQL listening port. I have started the SQL browser in services.

I have the IPv4 address of the SQL machine, but it doesn't look like it goes beyond the service provider.  I used "*what is my IP address*" to get the public IPv4 address, but it looks like it stops at the service provider. (tracert for this IP address shows `XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.dyn.serviceprovider.net`)

A. Can this be done?

B. Can this be done through the MS Access Linked table manager on each of the front end machines?

I need some specific directions on how to link an MS Access Front end remotely over the internet to the named SQL database Back-end per the conditions outlined above.

Many thanks for feedback and help.

Comment: Not programming question - you probably need to configure your router and confgure a Dynamic DNS provider

Comment: This isn't actually a programming question, it's a networking question. You'll need to setup a VPN between the clients and the server. Windows can do this, however I have no idea what licencing or software you would need. You might have better luck on https://superuser.com/ However from the programming side, if this is more than a couple of users, I'd recommend not doing it and porting the rest of the app to a technology that's built to do this. Access doesn't handle this very well and you'll end up with locking problems when you don't expect them.

Comment: First thing you need is a static IP. Once you have static IP then you can open ports from windows firewall and router firewall. Then you can access sql server by using that static IP

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. You need to "open" a port on the router/modem firewall on the side of the server. Every router is different but usually you login into the router web page, find the section with title port forwarding or games and there you need to define that port 1433 should be forward to the ip address of the server.

Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction. found a video How to connect SQL to internet which walked me through it.  Not pretty but best I can do with a client that doesn't use any shared internal drive space.